# Literature on Representation Theory of Graded Lie Algebras

Tags: resource-recommendations, representation-theory, lie-algebra, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

I am currently studying 'advanced' representation theory, including topics like super-Lie algebras. I've come across various gradings (excluding the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ grading), such as how to select odd roots in Dynkin diagrams, etc., but I couldn't find substantial literature on gradings or any other literature on the representations of graded Lie algebras.

I'm looking for literature that explains and addresses the significance of general gradings and their implications for representation. I've already gone through B. Hall and Fulton & Harris. The only paper that has somewhat helped me is [arxiv:1701.03704](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03704), where they discuss gradings in relation to Young diagrams. Does anyone have experience with this?